# java.lang.NullPointerException at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.io.ServerInputBuffer.getThreadPool

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, glassfish

I've got a project with JSF, without any filters (at least created by me) and with only one servlet. I've got an Exception during FilterChain execution. It happens periodically, maybe one time per five days, and I don't know the causes of it.

Stacktrace:

```
[2017-12-26T16:00:48.245+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [] [org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain] [tid: _ThreadID=28 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(4)] [timeMillis: 1514293248245] [levelValue: 900] [[
  GRIZZLY0013: Exception during FilterChain execution
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.io.ServerInputBuffer.getThreadPool(ServerInputBuffer.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.InputBuffer.invokeHandlerOnProperThread(InputBuffer.java:1081)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.InputBuffer.append(InputBuffer.java:975)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
]]
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: [Copypasting the exception in a search engine](https://www.google.com/search?q=java.lang.NullPointerException+at+org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.io.ServerInputBuffer.getThreadPool) gives among others [this bug report](https://github.com/javaee/grizzly/issues/1880) which says it's already fixed over a year ago. Have you already excluded this?

Comment: no, I tried to search only by first line of stacktrace. That can be the reason. Thanks.

Comment: I also searched with first line of the stack trace.

Comment: Can you please paste here your code ?